# Default authentication/authorization/accounting list on all lines?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, aaa

Am I correct that if one has not specified a named authentication list(`login authentication ...` under line configuration), authorization list(`authorization ..` under line configuration) or accounting list(`accounting commands 15 ..` under line configuration) then the default authentication/authorization/accounting list on all lines is named `default`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the default authentication/authorization/accounting list on all lines is named default?

Yes, 100% correct; quoting Cisco's docs...

- [Authentication](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/sec_user_services/configuration/guide/15_0s/sec_securing_user_services_15_0S_book/sec_cfg_authentifcn.html#wp1076037): *The default method list is automatically applied to all interfaces except those that have a named method list explicitly defined.*
- [Authorization](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/sec_user_services/configuration/guide/15_0s/sec_securing_user_services_15_0S_book/sec_cfg_authorizatn.html#wp1057392): Once defined, method lists must be applied to specific lines or interfaces before any of the defined methods are performed. *The only exception is the default method list (which is named "default"). If the aaa authorization command for a particular authorization type is issued without a named method list specified, the default method list is automatically applied to all interfaces or lines except those that have a named method list explicitly defined.*
- [Accounting](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/sec_user_services/configuration/guide/15_0s/sec_securing_user_services_15_0S_book/sec_cfg_accountg.html#wp1052893): Named accounting method lists allow particular security protocol to be designated and used on specific lines or interfaces for accounting services. *The only exception is the default method list (which is named "default"). The default method list is automatically applied to all interfaces except those that have a named method list explicitly defined.*